# Marketplace with Paypal & Stripe

Tags: flutter, paypal, payment-gateway, marketplace

we are currently creating an app for marketplace where we are hoping to get airbnb model implemented. Where buyer will pay the seller and we will take our cut from the seller. We actually don't want to get payment ourself for the sale and handle the disputes for order shipping or chargebacks.

The customer support from PayPal said, that there is not marketplace solution for small business & startups in Europe. But we need PayPal as an payment option in our marketplace.

My research so far:

- I heard, that you could connect PayPal & Stripe with zapier. But I don't know how to handle the payments through that solution.

Maybe someone had the same challenge and could help us with that.

Comment: If you want to accept payments and subscriptions with PayPal and many other payment methods through Stripe, check out https://easypie.shop | Shopping, Payment and Subscription Terminal